# Scrapy passing requests along

Tags: python, scrapy

I previously used some code like this to visit a page and change the url around a bit to generate a second request which gets passed to a second parse method:

```
from scrapy.http import Request


def parse_final_page(self, response):
  # do scraping here:

def get_next_page(self, response, new_url):
  req = Request(
      url=new_url,
      callback=self.parse_final_page,
  )
  yield req

def parse(self, response):
  if 'substring' in response.url:
      new_url = 'some_new_url'
      yield from self.get_next_page(response, new_url)
  else:
      pass
      # continue..
      # scraping items
      # yield
```

This snippet is pretty old (2 years or so) and i'm currently using Scrapy 2.2, although i'm not sure if that's relevant.  Note that `get_next_page` gets called, but `parse_final_page` never runs, which I don't get...

Why is `parse_final_page` not being called? Or more to the point.. is there an easier way for me to just generate a new request on the fly?  I would prefer to not use a `middleware` or change `start_urls` in this context.

Comment: Couldn't you just `yield Request(url=new_url, callback=self.parse_final_page)` from inside the `if` statement?

Comment: Yeah; I initially tried that but got the same result

Comment: Would be helpful if you posted a reproducible example or at least the logs of your execution. If you are yielding the Request and `parse_final_page` isn't being called, it's likely your request failed/got filtered/returned unexpected HTTP code. Running in DEBUG might help you spot the issue too.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea.  I have it wrapped in a try/except statement but it throws no errors, nothing in the logs.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to help you without your code or the scrapy execution logs. Also, executing you spider with `-L DEBUG` will show you exactly what became (and possibly returned) of the Request you yielded.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm going to edit once and add the logs.  I can see now getting a 302 redirect on one of the url's.

Answer (score 0):

1 - "**Why is parse_final_page not being called?**"

Your script works fine for me on Scrapy v2.2.1, so its probably an issue with the specific request you're trying to make.

2 - "**...is there an easier way for me to just generate a new request on the fly?**"

You could try this variation where you return the request from the `get_next_page` callback, instead of yielding it (note I removed the `from` keyword and did not send the response object to the callback):

```
def parse(self, response):
    if 'substring' in response.url:
        new_url = ''
        yield self.get_next_page(new_url)
    else:
        # continue..
        # scraping items
        # yield

def get_next_page(self, new_url):
    req = Request(
        url=new_url,
        callback=self.parse_final_page,
    )
    return req

def parse_final_page(self, response):

    # do scraping here:
```